# How to get the alias of of a Cell for MS Excel by using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel file, some cells in the file has alias, I want to loop all the cells in the file and print the one has an alias, I am using the Apache POI(the Java API for Microsoft Documents) to do this, but I didn't find the method to get an alias of a cell, please see my code below.

```
for (int i=0;i<wb.getNumberOfSheets();++i) {
    Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt ;
    for (Row row : sheet1) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            // Check if the Cell has an alias
        }
    }
}
```

How to add an alias for a Cell

Mouse click to select a cell in a Sheet, then edit the Name box(the one left to the function box) to input a alias for the cell and press enter, from this point, you can select the cell by clicking the drop down arrow at the right of the Name box and select the alias for it. see the picture for details.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this in your code:

1) first,you can get the alias name of the whole excel:

```
  int NameTotalNumber = workbook.getNumberOfNames();
```

2) then you can get them in your loop like this:

```
     for (int NameIndex =0; NameIndex<NameTotalNumber; NameIndex++)
    {
        Name nameList = wb.getNameAt(NameIndex);
        System.out.println( "AliasName: "+nameList.getNameName());  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have deliver this.

```
  for (int NameIndex =0; NameIndex<NameTotalNumber; NameIndex++)
    {
        Name nameList = wb.getNameAt(NameIndex);
        System.out.println( nameList.getNameName());     
    }
```